# Must I call session_set_save_handler() after session_write_close()?

Tags: php, session

I'm working in some legacy code which has a custom PHP session handler that is set up with `session_set_save_handler()`.  At some point, that code must release the session data to another process.  It calls `session_write_close()`, waits for the child process to finish, and then re-loads the session data by re-calling `session_set_save_handler()`, followed by `session_start()`.

1. `session_set_save_handler()`
2. `session_start()`
3. *read/modify session data*
4. `session_write_close()`
5. *execute child process which loads the session, modifies data, and writes session*
6. `session_set_save_handler()` **Is this step necessary?**
7. `session_start()`
8. *read data in session, possibly written by the prior child process*

Is it necessary to set the session save handler again?

Comment: Do you use a SessionHanlderInterface? e.g. SessionHandler?

Comment: @Rizier123 Currently the code is using a bunch of functions for `open`, `close`, `read`, `write`, etc., but I intend to move it to implement the `SessionHandlerInterface`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first I would recommend you to put:

```
session_write_close();
```

Before point 1, because if you have session auto on you will get an error since you have to call `session_set_save_handler()` before `session_start()`.

But now to the real question:

> 6. session_set_save_handler() Is this step necessary?

No it is not necessary! (But maybe you still want to call `session_write_close();` before you start your session again)

So why don't you have to call it again?

Because it's a configuration option which will keep the value during the entire script execution (and will be restored at the end of the script).

You can also clearly see this in the [php source code](https://github.com/php/php-src):

And a quote from there (/ext/session/session.c):

```
/* {{{ proto void session_set_save_handler(string open, string close, string read, string write, string destroy, string gc)
   Sets user-level functions */
static PHP_FUNCTION(session_set_save_handler)
{
    zval ***args = NULL;
    int i, num_args, argc = ZEND_NUM_ARGS();
    char *name;

    if (PS(session_status) != php_session_none) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    if (argc != 6) {
        WRONG_PARAM_COUNT;
    }

    if (zend_parse_parameters(argc TSRMLS_CC, "+", &args, &num_args) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (!zend_is_callable(*args[i], 0, &name TSRMLS_CC)) {
            efree(args);
            php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, "Argument %d is not a valid callback", i+1);
            efree(name);
            RETURN_FALSE;
        }
        efree(name);
    }

    zend_alter_ini_entry("session.save_handler", sizeof("session.save_handler"), "user", sizeof("user")-1, PHP_INI_USER, PHP_INI_STAGE_RUNTIME);

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (PS(mod_user_names).names[i] != NULL) {
            zval_ptr_dtor(&PS(mod_user_names).names[i]);
        }
        Z_ADDREF_PP(args[i]);
        PS(mod_user_names).names[i] = *args[i];
    }

    efree(args);
    RETURN_TRUE;
}
/* }}} */
```

You will see the function call of: `zend_alter_ini_entry()` which will change the value in the configuration for the script execution. So there is no need to call it again.

**EDIT:**

With `session_set_save_handler()` you will change the `session.save_handler string` configuration: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-handler